# how to find out the column dependencies of a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have written a query to find out column names of tables in the database.

```
SELECT 
  t.NAME AS TABLEName,
  SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + c.name AS ColumnName
FROM 
  sys.tables t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) LIKE '%Message%'
ORDER BY t.NAME
```

So far I've got the expected result, but whatever column I am looking I want to find out the dependency of column related tables. By executing the above query I am getting table names and column names.

How can I get the column related dependent tables?

Comment: What exactly does the 'dependency' mean to you? Are you looking for well defined foreign-key like relationship in the database or something else?

Comment: in the query i gave column name messageID.So i need to get message ID column dependent tables. what ever are there i need to get that tables depenedent on MessageID column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT KCU1.TABLE_CATALOG,
       KCU1.TABLE_SCHEMA,
       KCU1.TABLE_NAME,
       KCU1.COLUMN_NAME,
       KCU2.TABLE_NAME   AS REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
       KCU2.COLUMN_NAME  AS REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU1
       JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS RC
            ON  KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
            AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
            AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
       JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU2
            ON  KCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
            AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
            AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
            AND KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION
WHERE  KCU1.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Message%'
ORDER BY
       KCU1.TABLE_NAME,
       KCU1.COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. You will however need to tweak it a bit to suit your specific need:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referenced_major_id) AS ReferingObject, 
    (SELECT o.type_Desc FROM sys.objects o
        WHERE o.object_id = d.referenced_major_id) AS ReferingObjType,
CASE WHEN referenced_minor_id <> 0 THEN COL_NAME(referenced_major_id, referenced_minor_id)
        ELSE '' END AS RefColumnName,
OBJECT_NAME(object_ID) AS ReferencedObject,
(SELECT o.type_Desc FROM sys.objects o
        WHERE o.object_id = d.object_id) AS ReferedObjType 
fROM sys.sql_dependencies d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all tables/columns that reference a column in the table whose name contains token *Message*, you can use this:

```
;WITH PT AS (
    SELECT 
        tc1.TABLE_NAME, 
        tc2.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc1
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE tc2 
            ON tc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE tc1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY')
SELECT
    FK_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
    FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
    PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
    Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK 
        ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK 
        ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU 
        ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    JOIN PT 
        ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Message%'
ORDER BY
    FK.TABLE_NAME,
    CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    PK.TABLE_NAME,
    PT.COLUMN_NAME
```